# Depth map from HTC EVO 3D

Tags: android

I have a question.

Does evo 3d get depth map??
(the distance from real world objects to camera)

If it does, can developer use library to get the depth map??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get it by default. You have to compute it by yourself. For that purpose, you can use OpenCV 4 Android and use the stereo matching capability.
Check the following links :

- For the Idea : http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/08/opencv-stereo-matching.html
- From the OpenCV doc : http://docs.opencv.org/java/index.html?org/opencv/calib3d/StereoBM.html

Comment: Yes ! Depth map can be computed as long as you have two images of the same scene taken from different point of views. So, you first need to shot a picture with the 3D camera or treat the 3D preview, then separate left and right view, and finally apply one stereo matching algorithm in order to get disparities. (from which depth can be infered). But this might be slow as it requires quite a lot of processing.